# How to show a button at the bottom which is common for all tabs in jframe

Tags: java

I need a jbutton in jframe which is common for all tabs.

I tried by adding same jbutton to 3 tabs , but the button is visible only in the last added tab.

Here is my complete stand alone code.If you run this code you will get complete idea of my issue.

```
    final JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    JButton jbutton ;
    JTable table;   // Table 1 in 1st tab 
    JTable databaseTable; // Table 2 in 2nd tab
    JTable serverDetailsTable; // Table 3 in 3rd tab
    JFrame  frame = new JFrame();
    table = new JTable();
    final boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
              false, true, true
          };
      String [] columnNames = {
          "col1", "col2", "col3"};
      Object[][] mappedDeploymentData=
            { 
                 {" ", "", ""},
                 {" ", "", ""}
            };
         DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(mappedDeploymentData, columnNames)
         {
             public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return canEdit[column];
             }
         };
         table.setModel(tableModel);

      table.setModel(tableModel);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

      jbutton = new JButton(" Start "); //Button i want for all tabs in a frame
      jbutton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      jbutton.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
      jbutton.setEnabled(true);

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      panel.add(scrollPane);
      panel.add(jbutton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
      tabs.add("Tab1", panel);

      databaseTable = new JTable();
      final boolean[] canEdit1 = new boolean [] {
                false, false, true,true
            };
        String [] databaseColumns = {
            "col1", "col2","col3"};
        Object[][] mappedDatabaseData= { 
                 {" ", "", ""},
                 {" ", "", ""}
            };

         DefaultTableModel mappedDatabaseTablemodel = new DefaultTableModel(mappedDatabaseData, databaseColumns)
          {
              public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                 return canEdit1[column];
              }
          };

        databaseTable.setModel(mappedDatabaseTablemodel);
        JScrollPane databaseScrollPane = new JScrollPane(databaseTable);
        JPanel databasePanel = new JPanel();
        databasePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        databasePanel.add(databaseScrollPane);
        databaseTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        tabs.add("Tab2", databasePanel);


        serverDetailsTable = new JTable();  
        final boolean[] canEdit2 = new boolean [] {
                false, true
            };
        String [] server = {
            " col1", " col2"};
        Object[][] serverDeatils=
            { 
                 {"",""},
                 {"",""}
            };

         DefaultTableModel serverDatabaseTablemodel = new DefaultTableModel(serverDeatils, server)
          {
              public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                 return canEdit2[column];
              }
          };
          serverDetailsTable.setModel(serverDatabaseTablemodel);
          JScrollPane serverScrollPane = new JScrollPane(serverDetailsTable);
          serverScrollPane.setVisible(true);
          JPanel serverPanel = new JPanel();
          serverPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          serverPanel.add(serverScrollPane);
          serverDetailsTable.setTableHeader(null);
          tabs.add("Tab3", serverPanel);



    frame.setContentPane(tabs);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setTitle("Frame");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(900, 600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

If you run the above stand alone program you can see the button in first tab the same button i need to display in all tabs.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the button to the first tab only.

Consider creating a main panel instead, that will be the content pane of the frame, then add the tabbedpane and the button to it :

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
mainPanel.add(tabs, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.add(jbutton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
```

Also remove the following line, since you don't want to add the button to one particular tab :

```
panel.add(jbutton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```